# How to filter form data with custom model binder

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a bunch of forms where currency values are entered and I want them to be able to enter "$1,234.56". By default, the model binders won't parse that into a decimal.

What I am thinking of doing is creating a custom model binder the inherits DefaultModelBinder, override the BindProperty method, check if the property descriptor type is decimal and if it is, just strip out the $ and , from the values.

Is this the best approach?

Code:

```
public class CustomModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
 protected override void BindProperty( ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, System.ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor )
 {
  if( propertyDescriptor.PropertyType == typeof( decimal ) || propertyDescriptor.PropertyType == typeof( decimal? ) )
  {
   var newValue = Regex.Replace( bindingContext.ValueProvider[propertyDescriptor.Name].AttemptedValue, @"[$,]", "", RegexOptions.Compiled );
   bindingContext.ValueProvider[propertyDescriptor.Name] = new ValueProviderResult( newValue, newValue, bindingContext.ValueProvider[propertyDescriptor.Name].Culture );
  }

  base.BindProperty( controllerContext, bindingContext, propertyDescriptor );
 }
}
```

**Update**

This is what I ended up doing:

```
public class CustomModelBinder : DataAnnotationsModelBinder
{
    protected override void BindProperty( ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, System.ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor )
    {
        if( propertyDescriptor.PropertyType == typeof( decimal ) || propertyDescriptor.PropertyType == typeof( decimal? ) )
        {
            decimal newValue;
            decimal.TryParse( bindingContext.ValueProvider[propertyDescriptor.Name].AttemptedValue, NumberStyles.Currency, null, out newValue );
            bindingContext.ValueProvider[propertyDescriptor.Name] = new ValueProviderResult( newValue, newValue.ToString(), bindingContext.ValueProvider[propertyDescriptor.Name].Culture );
        }
        base.BindProperty( controllerContext, bindingContext, propertyDescriptor );
    }
}
```

Comment: take a look at this post from Haacked : http://haacked.com/archive/2011/03/19/fixing-binding-to-decimals.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's reasonable to do it in the binder. However, I think that `Decimal.Parse` with the currency format provider or number style ([see the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.parse.aspx)) would be more reliable than stripping the "$" and calling `base`. For starters, it would handle non-US currency, which might be an issue for you some day.

Comment: Wow. Didn't know Decimal.Parse had formatting that will accept that by default. You'd think there would be a way for the model binders to accept that by default then. In fact, on this example http://www.asp.net/%28S%28ywiyuluxr3qb2dfva1z5lgeg%29%29/learn/mvc/tutorial-39-cs.aspx they even have a decimal type with a regex validator that says a $ is ok... If I have a decimal type, a value of $1,234 or $1234 comes through as 0, and the model state isn't valid.

Comment: I looked through the MVC source and the DataAnnotationsModelBinder source, and I think it would be best to call base. There is a lot of stuff going on, including handling the errors and model state. I think doing what I was doing before, but using the decimal.Parse function instead will work nicely.

Answer (score 5):

In MVC3 you can just register a custom modelbinder that implements the IModelBinder interface specifically for decimal types and then tell it to handle currency or decimal by using the ModelMetaData.DataTypeName property on the bindingContext.

I've modified the sample provided by [Phil Haack in his article](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/03/19/fixing-binding-to-decimals.aspx) to demonstrate how it could be done:

```
    public class DecimalModelBinder : IModelBinder
    {

        public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            var valueResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
            var modelState = new ModelState { Value = valueResult };

            decimal actualValue = 0;
            try
            {

                if(bindingContext.ModelMetadata.DataTypeName == DataType.Currency.ToString())
                    decimal.TryParse(valueResult.AttemptedValue, NumberStyles.Currency, null, out actualValue);
                else
                    actualValue = Convert.ToDecimal(valueResult.AttemptedValue,CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);


            }
            catch (FormatException e)
            {
                modelState.Errors.Add(e);
            }

            bindingContext.ModelState.Add(bindingContext.ModelName, modelState);
            return actualValue;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create your own ValidationAttribute which checks if value has correct format. Then you could look if property is decorated with this attribute and bind it in proper way. Attribute doesn't need to be ValidationAttibute, but it seems like good idea.